# jQuery hover infinite loop

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover, jquery-hover

I'm trying to use .hover to make an HTML element  look like it's glowing.  My code looks like:

```
var glow = $('<div class="glow">...</div>');

$(this).hover(function() {
   glow.fadeIn();
}, function() {
   glow.fadeOut();
}
```

The effect I'm getting is that the fades just keep repeating over and over again on mouseover in an infinite loop.  When I look at the console, the hoverIn and hoverOut handler functions just keep getting called.

Any ideas what might be going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Would be nice if you could provide a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Please provide more code. Your `$(this)` makes me think that you may be assigning the `.hover()` as the result of another event, and therefore it is repeatedly being redundantly assigned.

Comment: The way I read that it seems like you're creating the `glow` div on hover, rather than fading in/fading out an existing div. (Admittedly, though, it's late, and I'm kinda tired...)

Comment: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c4ha7/1/

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use this code instead:

```
var glow = $('<div class="glow">...</div>');

glow.hover(function() {
   $(this).fadeIn();
}, function() {
   $(this).fadeOut();
}
```

or

```
var glow = $('<div class="glow">...</div>');

glow.hover(function() {
   glow.fadeIn();
}, function() {
   glow.fadeOut();
}
```

I believe right now your $(this) is ambiguous, and is probably not putting the hover() handler on the right object.

It's also possible that you've omitted something important here (as in, where is `glow` put into the DOM).

If worse comes to worse, you can skip `hover` entirely and just use `mouseover` and `mouseout` instead, or if you want to get *really* manual about the whole thing, you can use `bind` with the mouseover and mouseout events.

Actually, since you're seeing repetitive action on a single mouseover event, that might indicate that you've somehow bound many instances of your single `hover` handler to the `glow` object.  You can use `unbind` to remove the current handler before binding a new one if this ends up being the case, but avoiding the multiple binding is a better strategy if you can find a way to do so.

I hope this helps!

Comment: So that's not working.  The issue might be the context of the .hovers.  Basically, I'm running through the dom looking for elements that contain a certain class ("glow").  If the element has the class, I'm appending a new dom element.

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle that shows more of what I'm doing: http://jsfiddle.net/c4ha7/1/